# post a data to another URL by using .post() method in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, web.py

I have created a web.py URL,and it provides only 2 text boxes(No submit button).  When I  type a number in the first text field it should post the value into another URL.  By using AJAX `post()` I want to post the data to the second URL.  The second URL should return the data that I have posted, and it should display inside the second text box.  How can I solve this problem by using key up function and AJAX `post()` method?  I have tried a lot with `post()` method, but I couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: its always good to provide specific code that you're trying out.

Comment: There's something fishy about this question. It's not that hard to try and write ten lines of JavaScript before asking for help, especially that jQuery is [well documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){

  $("#textbox1").keyup(function(){ 
     if($(this).val()){
      $.post({
        url: "urlToPost",
        data: { "textbox1": $(this).val() },
        success: function(data){//make sure the server sends only the required data
          $("#textbox2").val(data);
        }
      });
     }  
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried the code in my web.py GET function,but it doest display the result in the 2nd text box.

Comment: Do you see the post being made from the page?

Comment: When you type something in textbox1 do you see any request being made from the page. Check in Firebug console or Net tab if you are using FF or keep and break point in the server side code and see if it gets called.

Comment: No sir,it doesn't request anything.i am using ubuntu,when i type in text field the terminal window only shows " 127.0.0.1:39369 - - [02/Aug/2011 11:30:15] "HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico" - 404 Not Found
"

Comment: What is the url that you are setting in this post settings?

Comment: Ok, and what is field name that you are looking for in this page? We are sending textbox1 as the data param.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution,Thanks for all the suggestions,i have attached my complete code here with the suggested changes.

```
import web

urls = (
  '/', 'first','/home','second')


app = web.application(urls, globals(), True)


class first:

    def GET(self):
        return'''
        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#text1").keyup(function(){
            var txt = $("#text1").val();
              $.post(
                "http://127.0.0.1:8080/home",
                 {text1 : txt},
                 function(result){
                 $("#text2").val(result);
              });
           });
         });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        Enter your text here  : <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1"/>
        You entered         : <input type="text" id="text2"/>
        </body>
        </html>'''

class second:

    def GET(self):
        return "Entered value goes here"

    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()
        n = i.text1
        return n


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you post what you have so far? this seems pretty straigth forward..

example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Bind to keyup + change to account for Copy/Paste with mouse button.
    $("#Textbox1Id").bind("keyup change", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'yoururl',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { value: $("#Textbox1Id").val() },
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#Textbox2Id').val(result.value);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                //Handle error
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
};
```

Shankar beat me to it... its basically the same answer just make sure you bind the change event also, and handle the any errors.